# How to read watchdog registers on x86 Linux?

Tags: memory, pci, x86, mmap, watchdog

I want to read the Intel iTCO watchdog registers on my Intel Lynx Point system. I found the watchdog here:

```
[ 5598.341020] iTCO_wdt iTCO_wdt.1.auto: Found a Lynx Point TCO device (Version=2, TCOBASE=0x1860)
```

It is connected to the ISA bridge LPC controller:

```
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. H87 Express LPC Controller
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
```

I found the ioports:

```
cat /proc/ioports | grep -i tco
1830-1833 : iTCO_wdt.1.auto
1830-1833 : iTCO_wdt
1860-187f : iTCO_wdt.1.auto
1860-187f : iTCO_wdt
```

And I found the iomem:

```
cat /proc/iomem | grep -i wdt
fed1f410-fed1f414 : iTCO_wdt.0.auto
```

I tried to dump the memory via:

```
memtool md 0xfed1f410
```

Then I set the timeout to a different value and compare the registers again:

```
wdctl -s 10
memtool md 0xfed1f410
```

Nothing changes, why is that? What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Not familiar with this device, but I do want to ask whether the kernel already understands it and if so whether you could just use `/dev/watchdog` in a normal manner?

Comment: Yes `/dev/watchdog` is available, `wdctl` uses it when setting a new timeout for example. My interest is how can I dump the registers from command line.